# Find $x$ such that $x+x^2+x^3=x^9-x^7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find $x$ such that $x+x^2+x^3=x^9-x^7$

I don't know how to do it, it is very difficult for me, I tried lot of things that failed. That's why I posted it here.

Comment: $0$ is the first solution.

Comment: What is $\;x\;$ ? A real number, a rational one, an integer, an element in a finite field...??

Comment: $x^9-x^7-x^3-x^2-x=(x^3-x-1)(x^5+x^2+1)x$

Comment: The first non-real solution is $x =\displaystyle \dfrac{-1}{6} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(\dfrac{27}{2}-\dfrac{3 \sqrt{69}}{2}\right)^{1/3}-\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \left(9+\sqrt{69}\right)\right)^{1/3}}{\left(2\times  3^{2/3}\right)}$ and the other aren't prettier ..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The expression can be factorised like such:
$$\begin{align}0&=x^9-x^7-x^3-x^2-x\\&\Downarrow\\0&=x (x^3-x-1) (1+x^2+x^5)\\&\Downarrow\\0&=x (x^3-x-1) (1+x^2 (1+x^3))\\&\Downarrow\\0&=x (x (x^2-1)-1) (1+x^2 (1+x^3))\end{align}$$
Now all you need to do is to solve the mini expressions within. Can  you take it from here?